# How does the Mithril network sustain itself?

Tags: cardano-node, mithril

I’ve been reading about [Parity Fether](https://medium.com/paritytech/parity-fether-is-on-ethereum-mainnet-105ed0c7b491), an Ethereum wallet powered by a light client and noticed that it’s discontinued in 2022. I couldn’t find why it was abandoned but after doing a bit digging I found some comments that criticized Parity’s lack of incentives to run light client servers. This made me wonder about Mithril and how Cardano might run into the same problem.

How will Cardano incentivize people to run the Mithril network? Will Mithril light clients charge a fee?

*p.s I can’t tag “Mithril” since my score is too low to create one*

*update: thanks for adding the tag*